# syntax to exclude a table with mysqldump

Tags: php, mysql

Going nuts. I don't find this exact line and using the example at the reference from MySQL, I'm obviously crossed-eyed here!

This is the wrong syntax but I'm not sure where to put the option --ignore-table=search_index and have tried many variations except the right one!

```
$cmd = "mysqldump -u --ignore-table=search_index " . $prod_db_user . " -p" . $prod_db_pass . " " . $prod_db_1 . " > " . $qa_backup_name;
```

I'm just trying to dump the database and exclude a table that is named search_index.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the `$prod_db_user` username after `-u`, as that is the username flag.

```
$cmd = "mysqldump -u{$prod_db_user} --ignore-table=search_index  -p{$prod_db_pass} $prod_db_1  > $qa_backup_name";
```

Since this is a double-quoted string, all the PHP variables can go directly into the string. However, be sure to escape them with [`escapeshellarg()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) first!.

```
$prod_db_user = escapeshellarg($prod_db_user);
$prod_db_pass = escapeshellarg($prod_db_pass);
// etc...
```

Finally, depending on the execution environment, it may be necessary to specify the full path to `mysqldump` (if it isn't otherwise found in the `$PATH` (or `%PATH%`) environment variable.

```
$cmd = "/path/to/mysqldump -u{$prod_db_user} ....";
```

Comment: well, it worked once but the 2nd time I got "Illegal use of option --ignore-table=<database>.<table>"...It only fails when I integrate the --ignore-table=search_index, otherwise the original and your idea works. I didn't, however, escape in either instance as above in the script, the actual variables are defined as in:

    $prod_db_user = "admin";

Comment: @kellyjohnson If you are specifying the database as `$prod_db_1`, then it doesn't make sense to exclude `database.table` anyway.

Comment: well, this is a Drupal install and drush isn't yet installed on that server. So the normal mysqldump copies all the cache tables and search index which makes a 608meg sql file! Excluding the search can bring that down at the very least 20% and probably more in this case. That's why I'm trying to exclude this table.